# Accessing multiple id columns, laravel join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am attempting to join three tables, and access the id column on two of them: Jobs - which shows details and job_interviews which holds the job status - accepted or declined.

Specifically, the problem that I am having is that I need to access both id fields: the jobs.id to allow user to see the details and the job_interviews.id to send his accept or decline response.

I set up my join like this:

```
public static function respondInterviews($jobID){
    return DB::table('job_interviews')
                ->join('jobs', 'jobs.id', '=', 'job_interviews.job_id')
                ->join('contractors', 'contractors.user_id', '=', 'job_interviews.send_to')
                ->where('jobs.user_id', '=', $jobID)
                ->select('jobs.id', 'job_interviews.id as interview_id', 'jobs.title', 'contractors.user_id', 'contractors.contact_name', 'job_interviews.status', 'jobs.created_at', 'jobs.budget', 'jobs.workType','job_interviews.send_to')
                ->get();
}
```

I have attempted to set the "id" columns apart by specifying

```
'job_interviews.id as interview_id',
```

Then in my page view I iterate through the list of interviews and then call the two id variables:

```
{{$interview->id}} //which accesses jobs.id and works great
{{$interview->interview_id}} //which is supposed to access job_interviews.id but is not working
```

The error that laravel is giving me is:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$interview_id
```

How do I access the job_interviews.id column?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with larval but your code looks right. So my solution would to be try changing the name around of the column while doing `var_dump($interview)` to see its in the object anywhere. The alternative is to double check that the query itself works. Either open a command window to your server or open a tool like mysql workbench and try the query there to make sure everything is coming back fine. If it is a primary key it should be there.

Comment: The job_interview.id does not appear to be in the query even though it is the primary key for the table.  I am really at a loss on why it isn't being pulled in.  The rest of the selected items are working fine.

Comment: Are you sure the user you are accessing the table with has read permissions on that data? I believe you can still do a join without read permissions.